# auto increment of a variable using awk

Tags: awk

I am trying to count the number of records between time periods.

```
doa
19560227
19560429
19571001
19571201
19580301
.
.
.
.
20170327
20170401
```

The time periods are in between a calender year like

```
19560101 to 19561231
19570101 to 19571231
.
.
.
20170101 to 20171231
```

whenever the date changes it should increment the variable.
I tried with the following code but could not get the result.

```
awk '{
  doa=$1
  cnt=1956

  for (i=19560101; i<=20171231; i=i+10000){
    if(doa >=i && doa <= i+1130){year${cnt}+=1}
  }

  print year${cnt}
  cnt+=1
}'
```

Please help.

Comment: Expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?:

```
$ awk '{a[substr($i,1,4)]++}END{for(i in a) print i, a[i]}' file
1956 2
doa 1
. 4
1957 2
1958 1
2017 2
```

As the ranges are calendar years, isn't it enough to count the years? If not, see my comment below.

If you want to output the whole range, do it in the `print`:

```
print i "0101 to " i "1231", a[i]
```

outputs

```
19560101 to 19561231 2
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But if it is not a calendar year, then how to proceed? suppose if the period is 19560401 to 19570331 and there on...

Comment: @var `{if(substr($i,5,4)>="0401") a[substr($i,1,4)]++; else a[substr($i,1,4)-1]++}` (untested, fixed > to >=, thou).